# .NET Environment.CurrentDirectory gets wrong directory when one project is dependent on another project

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I have two projects - API and Bl (business logic). My API project is dependent on `BL`.

Let's say I have a controller in the API project that uses some method from the `BL` project:

```
namespace API.Controllers
{
    [TestController]
    [Route("api/testcontroller")]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ISomeBlService _someBlService;

        public TestController(ISomeBlService someBlService)
        {
            _someBlService = someBlService;
        }

        [HttpGet("get")]
        public void Get()
        {
            var targetFilePath = _someBlService.BlMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace Bl.Services
{
    public class SomeBlService : ISomeBlService 
    {
        public string BlMethod()
        {
            var filePath = $"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}/{someFile.txt}";

            return $"got file path {filePath}";
        }
    }
}
```

The result I would want to get would be:

```
"C:\DotNetProjects\SampleWeb\Bl\bin\Debug\net7.0\someFile.txt"
```

but instead it is

```
"C:\DotNetProjects\SampleWeb\API\bin\Debug\net7.0\someFile.txt"
```

I get why this is happening, but is there a way to do the thing I want to do? Or should `Environment.CurrentDirectory` just be avoided if one project is calling another project?

Comment: But all of the code is running in the API, it has no knowledge of the BL folder at all. Why not just put the file you need in the API?

Comment: @DavidG I maybe need some time off (it's been quite a day) but based on the description it seems that OP is getting the Bl folder, not an API one for some reason. Though I would anticipate the opposite.

Comment: @GuruStron oh sorry my description was incorrect, im getting API folder when i want Bl, will fix the description

Comment: @GuruStron Suspect an error in question, there's no way they can be getting the BL folder

Comment: @Fjalee then it is not all lost for me. Yes, this is expected. The Bl.dll will be copied to the `API`'s build folder and when you will publish the project there would be no `Bl` folder at all.

Comment: @DavidG yes, I was too (hence the "Though I would anticipate the opposite.")

Comment: @GuruStron Either way, I think we both deserve some time off :)

Comment: Hmmm ok so I see there is probably no way to do this. I wanted to do this to have kidna seperate layers of API and Bl, I thought its a good practise to make Bl layer "know nothing" about API layer

Comment: What makes you think BL knows anything about API here?

Comment: @Fjalee Bl should not nothing about API layer, yes. What is the `someFile.txt` actually? Possibly you can either make it embed into the dll as resource or just make it being copied on build/publish.

Comment: Also some argument can be made that `someFile.txt` should be part of the API and provided as dependency/parameter when `Bl` is called.

Comment: Hmmm probably a bad thing i didnt actually explain what is sthat file, that file is an executable file that Business logic uses, so id think it should belong to the Bl project. If you know what YoutubeDl is, its the exetucable file that nugget package for youtubeDl uses

Comment: I think you may have fundamentally misunderstood what `Environment.CurrentDirectory` does. It returns the current directory of the executing process. That doesn't change based on which bit of code is calling it.

Comment: @JonSkeet yeah I think I understand that, but im wondering if there is a way to do what I want to do (usign some other methods rather than `Environment.CurrentDirectory`)

Comment: If your aim is to include files with individual assemblies, I think you should look at embedded resources instead of simple files.

Comment: hmm yeah I know nothing about embedded resources, will definetly check that, thanks for information !